# Fabricjs Add text to the center of rectangle

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I have circle and rectangles inside. I want to assign numbers and asterisk chars.
This is how it looks now:

[image]

As you can see, numbers located fine, but asterisks don't. They should be located under numbers. I won't copy code here, just have a look at [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/luzocituze/1/edit?js,console,output).

Adding asterisk chars starts in `markAsterisk` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to calculate the asterisk position in the same way you calculate the number position but with a slightly smaller radius (minus 10 in your case I guess) and store that for later use in the config array.

```
var rectConfig = Object.assign({
    left: canvas.getHeight() / 2 + rectRadius * Math.cos(radAngle),
    top: canvas.getWidth() / 2 + rectRadius * Math.sin(radAngle),
    aLeft: canvas.getHeight() / 2 + (rectRadius-10) * Math.cos(radAngle),
    aTop: canvas.getWidth() / 2 + (rectRadius-10) * Math.sin(radAngle),
    angle: angle + 90,
    originX: "center",
    originY: "center"
}
```

I named it here `aLeft` and `aTop` for the asterisks position.
See the `(rectRadius-10)` for the position with the smaller radius.
Change that if you want more offset.

and use this position in your `addAsteriks` function:

```
number.set('top', rect.aTop);
number.set('left', rect.aLeft);
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsbin.com/qicowimiwo/1/edit?js,output)